# How to assert for text in a nested element with enzyme Shallow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component which renders another component, I am creating it with shallow like this:

```
const component = shallow(<ABC {...props} />);
```

when I run `component.html()` - I can see this output

```
    <div class="abc">
      <div data-attribute1="hi" class="dynamically generated">
        First
      </div>
      <div data-attribute2="bye" class="dynamically generated">
        second
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'd like to write an assertion to check that the text "First" is there.

I've tried various combinations e.g. `find(ABC2).find('[attribute1="hi"]')` ABC2 is the component that is rendered inside ABC and it shows correctly in the html output but I can't seem to figure out how to assert the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this assertion:

```
  expect(component.find("div.random1").text()).toBe(
    "First"
  );
```

This will look for all the div tags with the class random1 and will try to assert that the text it contains is First, this assumes you only have 1 div with that class.

You can see more on this in the enzyme API:

https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/text.html

Comment: sorry I'll update the question, the classes are generated dynamically so I can't depend on their value.

Comment: Also the first find has to be on 'ABC2' which is the component that is being called inside 'ABC' and returns the divs...from what I understand.

Comment: So how can you assure the first ins going to be the first?  because attribute1 is not a valid html attribute for the div tag. I also think you can test that the second div is the one that should have the First text, so you can change the query to be like component.find("div").at(1).text() if you know that the second div will always be first assuming the first is the wrapper for all the options.

Comment: I'll update the attribute value so it's valid. I think the first find needs to be on ABC2 component doesn't it? as thats what's returned by the ABC component

Comment: If the ABC2 component holds the first, second divs and so on, it should be on that test, keep in mind that shallow only tests the component you're shallowing, so their child components won't be display, just the <ComponentName />